# Firefox width/interval of numerals

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox numerals has different interval:

[image]

But it's normal in Chrome:

[image]

How to correct that?

css:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li {display: inline-block;;}
ul {display: inline;}
ul.submenu {
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: justify;
display: none;
}
ul.submenu > li > a {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 3px;
}
ul.submenu > li > a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
ul.menu > li:hover > ul.submenu {display: block;}
```

html:

```
<body>
<ul class="menu">
<li><button>Pick</button><ul class="submenu"><li>
<a href="91">091</a><a href="92">092</a><a href="93">093</a><a href="94">094</a><a href="95">095</a><a href="96">096</a><a href="97">097</a><a href="98">098</a><a href="99">099</a><a href="100">100</a><br><a href="101">101</a><a href="102">102</a><a href="103">103</a><a href="104">104</a><a href="105">105</a><a href="106">106</a><a href="107">107</a><a href="108">108</a><a href="109">109</a><a href="110">110</a><br><a href="111">111</a><a href="112">112</a><a href="113">113</a><a href="114">114</a><a href="115">115</a><a href="116">116</a><a href="117">117</a><a href="118">118</a><a href="119">119</a><a href="120">120</a><br><a href="121">121</a><a href="122">122</a><a href="123">123</a><a href="124">124</a><a href="125">125</a><a href="126">126</a><a href="127">127</a><a href="128">128</a><a href="129">129</a><a href="130">130</a><br><a href="131">131</a><a href="132">132</a><a href="133">133</a><a href="134">134</a><a href="135">135</a><a href="136">136</a><a href="137">137</a><a href="138">138</a><a href="139">139</a><a href="140">140</a></li>
</ul></li></ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
ul.submenu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 24px;
}
```

or

```
ul.submenu > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 8%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/2Lobt5rf/1/

Comment: Awesome thanks Mam i like your answer thanks @madalina taina

Comment: @ivinraj Thank you for your kind words! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I can't believe You Mam But You easily solved....thanks once again God bless You...@madalina taina

Comment: @ivinraj don't overdo it so  xD

Comment: I can understand sir am extremely very sorry @user25